# How to backup transaction log after database backup everyday in SQL server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

How to backup transaction log after database backup everyday in SQL server 2005

Comment: Are you trying to shrink the size of the transaction log?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use SSIS to backup the log, so it can backup, then copy it to where it needs to be.

**UPDATE:**

You can look at this question, it talks about how to go from SQL Server 2005 query to an Excel file:
http://www.experts-exchange.com/Microsoft/Development/MS-SQL-Server/DTS/Q_23090779.html

The useful answer is:

> 1. Create a stored procedure that will have the output you need to export in
>      excel.
> 2. In the DTS package add a SQL connection and an excel conection. SQL
>      conn should point you server and db
>      and excel conn your file. If it
>      doesn't exist just create one on the
>      fly.
> 3. Create the Transformation task betreen the SQL conn and excel conn.
> 4. Double click on the arrow and in the trasformation data task properties
>      window in Source tab instead of
>      Table/View pick SQL query. In the
>      panel below type EXEC sprocname, where
>      sprocname will be the name of your
>      procedure from step 1.
>      5.Click on Destination tab; if file/worksheet if doesn't exist will
>      open a dialog window for creation.
>      Edit if you want and click OK.
> 5. In Transformations tab define your trasnfromation by matching the
>      columns. 7 Run.

If you want to run this automatically you need in an ongoing matter what you need is to define a Dynamic properties tasl where you can edit the excel connection to generate a name that will have a timestamp, (you can use an sql statement as well) and then in an Active X task create/copy the file from an existing structure file.

So

Dynamic Property Task ---> ActiveX task (copy from struct file to new generated name file ) ---> SQL conn ------> Excel conn.

Comment: How do I do that ? How do I use SISS to backup the log file ?